# What exactly counts as "connected" research nodes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I'm working on Thaumcraft 4.0 research, and I can't seem to pin down what exactly it will accept as a "connected" research node. I know there has to be a straight line path between research nodes, but how far away can they be? Ideally, the more I can save on research points by maximizing the efficiency of as few research aspects as possible, the better.

Comment: there are lines connecting the research nodes just look at those

Comment: @ratchetfreak I kind of want to know how close nodes have to be for the lines to show up...

Comment: it'll become moot next version anyway if the new research system I saw on forgecraft remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chain cannot form if there is more than one open space between active runes or nodes.

More info at the Wiki: [Thaumcraft 4 Crafting](http://thaumcraft-3.wikia.com/wiki/Research_in_Thaumcraft_4)

[image]

*This is how it should look like.*

Comment: You can skip one vertical and one horizontal open space.